# How to use TensorFlow LSTM tutorial for character-level language modeling?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to implement RNN character-level language model from Andrej Karpathy's blog http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/
using TensorFlow RNN. For starters, I took ptb_word_lm.py from the LSTM tutorial in TensorFlow, and changed the reader function, so that now instead of the original PTB dataset with 10000 distinct words it is trained on a stream of 36 distinct characters. (The shape of embedding was reduced accordingly: to 36x36 instead of 10000x200). The training/validation set was the text of War and Peace (3.5 million lowercase chars).

I expected a straightforward carryover. 
Instead, after about 20 runs RNN gets stuck in a state with over-represented T's in the beginning and end of words, A sample output starts looking like this after 5 or so epoch runs:
OF TrTSONAL TY tO tHE soS OF TOERE  AHME  AND TOmSEDtik  aN TEpoUNCENG THE soSECTIOaELING OF THE sNTIFiNDENTE OF TNE S sWN srrSONAL TY  TUT TN tF T  IauGR  aHE seW sisWoeID Tt WS tHuE thaT th wONNOT seeL THa sorEMENT OF THE sMRTH  AUT te T VITTENG Tt  sNPENelITY OiRhREAVEDTN T OORD

(here capital letters stand for higher likelyhood). No further progress is made over the next 100+ epoch runs. Perplexities are quickly frozen around 4 for train set, and 3.75 for validation set.

It is true that among all the character pairs in a typical text, "space-T" and "T-space" are the most frequent, but RNN is supposed to resolve such issues,right?  I tried varying parameters (ADAM for gradient, longer step, forget-bias=1.0, etc) - nothing changes.
I am at the end of my rope. What could be going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Comment: try training for a longer time with a tiny learning rate, like 1e-4 and adam

Comment: I am using Adam, which sets up its own learning rate. Perplexity is going down on both train and validation set, but at increasingly tiny rate. Ran for 100 epochs so far, the last 80 of them with no visibly significant output change. Am going to persist for another day. (On my PC, 10 epochs with RNN of 2 layers x 200 hidden vars take over an hour, so I have another couple of days ahead of me

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your initialization? Learning can get stuck if the gradient is at zero. This would happen if you initialize weights (or bias) to either zeroes or ones. There are different initialization alternatives, depending on your activation (non-linearity). A well rounded initialization would be normal or truncated normal.

e.g. `tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1)`

for bias, small constant also works `tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out])`